# How can I create a legend for my scatter plot which matches the colours used in the plot?

Tags: matplotlib, colors, legend, scatter-plot

I've created a scatter plot (actually two similar subplots) using `matplotlib.pyplot` which I'm using for stylometric text analysis. The code I'm using to make the plot is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

clusters = 4
two_d_matrix = np.array([[0.00617068, -0.53451777], [-0.01837677, -0.47131886], ...])
my_labels = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

fig, (plot1, plot2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(20, 10))

plot1.axhline(0, color='#afafaf')
plot1.axvline(0, color='#afafaf')
for i in range(clusters):
    try:
        plot1.scatter(two_d_matrix[i:, 0], two_d_matrix[i:, 1], s=30, c=my_labels, cmap='viridis')
    except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
        pass
plot1.legend(my_labels)
plot1.set_title("My First Plot")

plot2.axhline(0, color='#afafaf')
plot2.axvline(0, color='#afafaf')
for i in range(clusters):
    try:
        plot2.scatter(two_d_matrix[i:, 0], two_d_matrix[i:, 1], s=30, c=my_labels, cmap='viridis')
    except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
        pass
plot2.legend(my_labels)
plot2.set_title("My Second Plot")

plt.show()
```

Because there are four distinct values in `my_labels` there are four colours which appear on the plot, these should correspond to the four clusters I expected to find.

[image: The colours which appear in the plot]

The problem is that the legend only has three values, corresponding to the first three values in `my_labels`. It also appears that the legend isn't displaying a key for each colour, but for each of the axes and then for one of the colours. This means that the colours appearing in the plot are not matched to what appears in the legend, so the legend is inaccurate. I have no idea why this is happening.

[image: Labels which appear in plot]

Ideally, the legend should display one colour for each unique value in `my_labels`, so it should look like this:

[image]

How can I get the legend to accurately display all the values it should be showing, i.e. one for each colour which appears in the plot?

Comment: @medium-dimensional I tested it before uploading and it worked for me. What error is it giving? The only thing I couldn't provide in my code here was the full `two_d_matrix` array, as it was too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `plot1.legend` or `plot2.legend`, you can pass `label = None` to `plot1.axhline` or `axvline` (and similarly to `plot2.axhline` or `plot2.axvline`.) This will make sure it doesn't interfere with plotting legends of the scatter points and also not label those lines.

To get labels for all categories of scatter points, you'll have to call `plot1.scatter` or `plot2.scatter` by passing the label and choosing only values from `two_d_matrix` whose index matches with the index of label in `my_labels`.

You can do it as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some (pseudo) random data which is reproducible
generator = np.random.default_rng(seed=121)
matrix = generator.uniform(size=(40, 2))
matrix = np.sort(matrix)

clusters = 4
my_labels = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Select data points wisely
for i in range(clusters):
    pos = np.where(my_labels == i)
    ax.scatter(matrix[pos, 0], matrix[pos, 1], s=30, cmap='viridis', label=i)  

ax.axhline(0, color='#afafaf', label=None)
ax.axvline(0, color='#afafaf', label=None)

ax.legend()
ax.set_title("Expected output")
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

---

**Comparison of current output and expected output**

Observe how data points selection (done inside the `for` loops in the code below) affects the output:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some (pseudo) random data which is reproducible
generator = np.random.default_rng(seed=121)
matrix = generator.uniform(size=(40, 2))
matrix = np.sort(matrix)

clusters = 4
my_labels = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# Question plot
for i in range(clusters):
    ax[0].scatter(matrix[i:, 0], matrix[i:, 1], s=30, cmap='viridis', label=i)  

ax[0].axhline(0, color='#afafaf', label=None)
ax[0].axvline(0, color='#afafaf', label=None)

ax[0].legend()
ax[0].set_title("Current output (with label = None)")

# Answer plot
for i in range(clusters):
    pos = np.where(my_labels == i) # <- choose index of data points based on label position in my_labels
    ax[1].scatter(matrix[pos, 0], matrix[pos, 1], s=30, cmap='viridis', label=i)  

ax[1].axhline(0, color='#afafaf', label=None)
ax[1].axvline(0, color='#afafaf', label=None)

ax[1].legend()
ax[1].set_title("Expected output")

plt.show()
```